# Non-code related topics on Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is there a place for non-code related topics in the documentation?

One example I had in mind is my post on [Java-9 String implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213239/what-is-java-9s-new-string-implementaion) which people may have questions about, but there is no real code to explain it. Is there a place for this type of information too?

Answer (score 4):

It's OK for an example to not have code.  It's also OK to stick that content in Remarks (if it makes sense for it accompany examples).

We expect code to be common in Documentation (we're developers after all) but it isn't a hard requirement.  Useful, canonical content for developers is the goal - and plain text can serve that too.

Comment: The only problem is that you can't create a topic without an example. This then means that you need to create a dummy example.

Answer (score 1):

Post those in the "Remark" part of the topic. That's what's mainly used for information about a specific aspect of a language.